# Excel VBA Automation Error The Interface Error is unknown

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel \ Office 365.  I have a VBA macro with the below code that is attempting to scrape a webpage:

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim ecoll As Object
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
Set doc = ie.Document
Set ecoll = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
End Sub
```

When I execute it I receive the error:

[image]

And this line is highlighted:

```
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
```

I have these references ticked:

[image]

Microsoft states that is a valid ReadyState.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `= 4` at the end? `Readystate` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: You need to change the condition in your `Until`-clause: `Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.

Comment: I still receive the same error if I remove the = 4

Comment: Fwiw, I tried the code (with just `ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` and the OP's references), and it worked fine with no errors (`ecoll` has value "object"). I am on Windows 10, using Excel / Office 365. So, perhaps the error is elsewhere?

Comment: If you try `Debug.Print READYSTATE_COMPLETE` in a separate test `Sub`, what does it return in `Immediate Window`? If not 4, then use `ie.ReadyState = 4`...